# TypeEr Cannot set property 'index' of undefined extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:211:32

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

**Cannot set property 'index' of undefined in webpack.
I am following a video lecture and got this error of which I got no help on google.**

***In Webpac/dist/index.js***

```
    chunks.forEach((chunk, i) => {
              const extractedChunk = extractedChunks[i];
              extractedChunk.index = i;
              extractedChunk.originalChunk = chunk;
              extractedChunk.name = chunk.name;
```

***In custom file webpack.config.js***

```
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
    const path = require("path"); 
    module.exports = {
      entry: "./config.js",
      output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/javascripts"),
      },
    };
    module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: "style-loader",
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "css-loader",
                  options: {
                  minimize: true,
                  },
    
                },
              ],
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("../stylesheets/app.css")],
      
    };
    
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV9m1.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiMj0.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjRih.png
```

Comment: Entry point 
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './public/stylesheets/style.css';

$(function(){

});